# What security issue when "Manage loginState by sending JWT as cookie"?

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, jwt

Required:
1.Selectable temp login (when shoutdown will logout)
2.When Internet down still can just press logout and go away.

I know refresh token&access token solution,but I think sending JWT by cookie faster and more secure.
Some discuss about this but someone thought this as strange shortcuts.
Why? Any security problem?

---

The following is what a build for a forum.

### Login: Back-End(B-End) store the JWT(with userId,random-key) in User's loginRecord DB(UserLoginDB).

1. Using set-cookie :
   -"JWT"(set HttpOnly+secure+sameSite:'lax'. When select keepLogin the cookie will have 1 month maxage, or be session cookie delete after shoutDown. )
   -"Login-Cookie"(set HttpOnly=false. Has random-key same as in JWT.)
2. Response some basic userInfo to store in LocalStorage let Vue to render(With a login=true in LocalStorage JS for can't detect JWT).

### Doing any login-need action: B-End will check:

1. JWT vaild (If expired will go to DB check recorded and update to the new one.)
2. Check Login-Cookie's random-key are match in JWT.
   If (not match/undefined){auto logout }else{keep going}
   (JWT is HttpOnly& cookie has been signed. No need to encrypt random-key in JWT.)

### Logout

1. B-end delete UserLoginDB, delete all cookies.
2. F-end set login=false in LocalStorage.
3. F-end delete Login-Cookie, so when Internet down the cookie still be removed.
   As I know OAuth 1.0 can't cope with this.(2.0 not sure.)

### Cut off power(Jump window.onbeforeunload) (Working for those not select keepLogin)

1. Session cookie deleted (We faced F-End can't detect this for HttpOnly,so new user will saw what's lastTime login despite can't do login-action.)
2. When open new website/tabs detect Login-Cookie, if unexist set login=false in LocalStorage.

### Only 2 situation need to check User's loginRecord DB

1. JWT will expired within 3 hours, then B-end will auto check DB is recoreded then update a new JWT & Login-Cookie.
2. When some crutial action,likes: Change password etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I vote to close this post, because it seems to not be a question anymore. Please delete it or turn it back into a question and answer it in an answer post.